# Way to extract wordpress data from folder backup

Tags: mysql

Before my HDD crashed, I backed up the C:\wamp folder. Can I extract the wordpress posts/pages using another localhost on a different pc?

Answer (score 1):

There's two elements to this:

1. Restoring the mySQL database which hopefully resided in your `wamp` folder. This will be where the actual post data is in.

   See

   - [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484750)
   - [Restore MySQL database folder from a recovered Hard 
     Disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10680261)
2. Restoring the files themselves. The most straightforward way to do this will be to restore a wamp install from scratch with the same paths and host names as you had before the crash, and then copying the Wordpress files from the backup folder into the new live folder.

Unless you manage to recreate everything 1:1, you may need to adjust

- the mySQL password in the WP install (I think it's in `wp-config.php`)
- path and/or host names; for how to do that, see [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)